# Bash mkdir with a datetime stamp

Tags: bash, date, mkdir

To make a directory including some information, the server name, and a date, I am using:

```
mkdir ~/abcd-$(home -f)-$(date +"Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

trying to get `~/abcd-servername-20130418210802`

I get a `?` on the end.  If I use a variable and a substring (ie, `{STR1:0:29}`) function, I get one or more `?`.  Just an annoyance really but would like to know why.

Comment: Are you editing the script on Windows? Sounds like you have DOS-style line ends, with a \r before \n.

Answer (score 2):

Tested on openSUSE 42.3:

```
NEWCOMPUTER=`uname -n`
THEDATE=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
mkdir ~/Desktop/computers/$NEWCOMPUTER-$THEDATE
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 'non-graphic' characters in your directory name.  From the man page for `ls`:

> -q  Force printing of non-graphic characters in file names as the
>                character `?'; this is the default when output is to a terminal.

Additionally it looks like your directory has some problems as you stated it.  Your `Y` should be `%Y` and your `home` should be `hostname` (but you haven't stated your operating system).

Comment: Operating system is Linux 2.6.18.  Script was edited onn the server.  Just want to get rid of unwanted characters.